# Is it advisable to talk about "learning things I don't know in the field" as one of the plans for future in statement of intent?

Tags: graduate-admissions, statement-of-purpose

I am going to have a slight change in my field of study which is acceptable by the faculty I'm applying in for Master's. But because of this difference, I assume, I probably know less about the field than a Bachelor's graduate of the new field. In my statement of purpose, should I express that I'm willing to take care of the missing credits and I'm eager to learn what I don't know?

Comment: I think it will benefit if you mention which country you're applying for. Here in Australia there's Masters by Coursework (you mainly do courses) and Masters by Research (where you focus fully on research). Both require a completely different approach to writing a statement of intent.

Comment: Canada. Yeah, it's the same here. I'm aiming for the Research one. Can you tell me how the approaches are different?

Comment: I think a clear difference is that by Coursework your purpose would be to expand your knowledge in that field through subjects, which you can select, while for Research you most likely need to have some background and you have a certain research goal (something you like to investigate). With coursework you're not really 'investigating', you 'simply' follow the subjects. Of course, in any research you also learn new items - which does not necessarily have to come from subjects though.

Comment: Now I see. So if I've understood correctly, you suggest that for Coursework it might be OK but for research it doesn't help, right?

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm the right person to suggest what you should or should not write... it's all personal. I think I'll combine it all into an answer because the text is getting big!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I don't want to say what you should or should not write, this is my suggestion.

There is a difference between a Masters by Coursework and Masters by Research, as in the latter you most likely will be asked to provide a new contribution to science, while for the former you will most likely 'simply' extend your knowledge through subjects.

Knowing it's an application for Masters by Research, I suggest reading up on the research you're interested in, mention why you're interested in it and how you can contribute to that field. I think the reviewers are more interested in your enthusiasm and how you can contribute.

Mentioning that you're willing to take credits is a sign that you're afraid of not knowing enough, and could be a sign for reviewers that you're not confident. On the other hand, it does show that you know your limitations - but when you decide to mention it, don't make it the main item of your letter.

In the research field however the learning does not always happen through subjects, it most often occurs through literature review. Although subjects are very beneficial if exactly in the area of research, I think that it's sufficient to demonstrate that you are capable of working in the field of study.